# Given the joint distribution P(1,1) and P(0,0) of P(X,Y), how do i find P(0,1) and P(1,0)?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Given the joint distribution $P(X,Y)$ where $P(0,0) = 0.25$ and $P(1,1)= 0.6$.

$X$ and $Y$ can only take the values of $\{0,1\}$. Also it is given that $X \sim \textrm{Bern(p)}$. I've been searching for countless hours trying to find formulas to on how will $X \sim \textrm{Bern(p)}$ or the other given joint distribution help me find the others.

Edit: I just realized that I made a mistake. Instead of typing them as conditional probabilities, i typed them as joint probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a table

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} X \backslash Y&0&1& \sum\\ \hline 0 &0.25 & & 1-p \\ \hline 1 & & 0.6 & p\\ \hline \sum & & &   1   \end{array}$$

Since $X$ is bernoulli distributed we have two states, $0$ and $1$. The probability for state $1$ then is $p$. Thus $P(X=1)=p$ and $P(X=0)=1-p$

For a specific value of p the remaining values can be calculated with simples algebra.

Comment: Its a little weird because the entry for X=1 and Y=0 will be negative

Comment: @Duts Yes, that's true. So there is a contradiction wth these given values. So there is a mistake in the exercise. But with this I cannot help. Maybe it is $p=0.67$

Comment: I know the mistake. I actually was very wrong in the question i posted. It was supposed to be conditional probabilities and not joint probability. The real question is also up now [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397132/how-to-find-all-px-i-y-j-of-the-random-variables-x-and-y). Would appreciate it if you can take a look at it

Comment: @Duts It seems that you've deleted the question. And I've adjusted my answer for a general p.

Comment: sorry about that. I've undeleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the law of total probability tells us

$$P(X=1)=P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0).$$

Use this to solve $P(X=1,Y=0)$. Finally, use the fact

$$1=P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=0)$$

to solve $P(X=0,Y=1)$.

Comment: is P(X=x) = X ~ Bern(p=x)?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. $P(X=1)=X$ makes no sense. One is a probability and one is a random variable.

Comment: P(X=x) is not given to us but they did give us X~Bern(p=x). are those the same thing?

Comment: $X\sim Bern(p)$ means $X$ has two point support $\{0,1\}$ where $P(X=1)=p$

Comment: Do you mean p-1? I think your comment got cut. But thank you!

Comment: My comment did not get cut; I meant it as I wrote it. Stack exchange inserts the hyphen after every comment

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Im not sure either. I did upvote.